# Finding it difficult to display data that is displayed on the console to display in the view

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I have a Firestore database which looks like this.
I am currently retrieving data from the userFavorites collection.
 [image]

My Favorite Service

```
   async getfavoriteList(): Promise<firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot> {
    const user: firebase.User = await this.authService.getUser();
    if (user) 
          {
    this.FavoriteListRef = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`userFavorites`);
    return this.FavoriteListRef.where('uid', '==', user.uid).get();
              }
           } 
       }
```

Favorite TS

```
  favoriteList: any; 
  public favoriteListRef: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;


    this.favoriteService.getfavoriteList().then(favoriteListSnapshot => {
      this.favoriteList = [];
      favoriteListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.favoriteList.push({
          id: snap.id,
          favoriteList: snap.data().favourite
        });
        console.log(snap.data().favourite)
        return false;
      });
    });
  }
```

Now, When I console.log this data using -- console.log(snap.data().favourite) ,

I see the data in the console.

[image]

However, this data is not displaying in the view with the following HTML I have tried.
I have also tried dumping out the data with JSON pipe.

```
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12" >
        <ion-card *ngFor ="let favorite of favoriteList">
           <!--  <img [src]="favorite?.image[0]">
            <img [src]="favorite?.favorite.image[0]"> -->
          <div class="card-title">{{ favorite | json }}</div>
        <div>{{favorite?.description}}</div>
        </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: poor Question naming :)

Comment: favoriteList maybe empty

Comment: you can try displaying it as is with `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created an array:

```
this.favoriteList = [];
```

then you are pushing an item:

```
 this.favoriteList.push({
      id: snap.id,
      favoriteList: snap.data().favourite
    });
```

So your have nested array:

```
 favoriteList[i].favoriteList // you should iterate here
```

So the code should look like this:

```
    <ion-card *ngFor ="let favorite of favoriteList">   
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of favorite?.favoriteList">
            <img [src]="item.image[0]">
            <div class="card-title">{{ item | json }}</div>
            <div>{{item?.description}}</div>
        </ng-container>
    </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are populating your array in an async way, the first time your html parses the array it is still empty. However since you are not providing a new reference for this array when you are populating it, Angular does not refresh its view. So you either need to run manual changetection after you know the array is full or you can do something like:

```
private favoriteListDisplay = new BehaviourSubject<any[]>([]);
```

and then instead of your console.log you can do:

```
this.favouriteListDisplay.next(this.favoriteList)
```

and then your html:

```
 <ion-card *ngFor ="let favorite of favoriteListDisplay | async">
```

this way you will tell angular to trigger another cycle of detecting changes and displaying your data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping through `favoriteList` with `<ion-card *ngFor ="let favorite of favoriteList">`.  The structure of `favoriteList` is an array of object with each object having and `id` and and `favoriteList` array.

```
{
  id: snap.id,
  favoriteList: snap.data().favourite
}
```

In your template you're trying to access properties that do not exist on the `favoriteList`.